# Synonyms For Tall?

Tags: synonyms

Hello there everyone!

I have to write this 15,000 word "book" for E.L.A., and I need an unbelievably stupendous word for 'tall'.

I can't think of a really good synonym, and I'm getting tired of thinking. PLEASE comment below!

Synonym for 'Tall'?

Comment: Where have you looked? If you haven't looked, go do that now :-) If you have, what have you seen? Why do you dislike what you've seen? What are you planning to apply the word to? (A person? A building? A story?) We **really** need to know more information before we can give you any sort of help. As it is, we can't see any of the work you've already put in, and we need to.

Comment: **"quite tall"**.....

Comment: I can say  "a towering building" but less likely with mountain. An *immense mountain* works but not an *immense person* which might be misinterpreted. So use an adverb such as "he's staggeringly/astonishingly/amazingly/remarkably tall"

Answer (score 2):

The most outlandish synonym I have found is Brobdingnagian (with capital letter), with the meaning "marked by tremendous size". It refers to Brobdingnag, a fictional country in Jonathan Swift's classic novel Gulliver's Travels (1726). It is found [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Brobdingnagian) on the Oxford Dictionary site, and [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brobdingnagian) on the Merriam-Webster Dictionary site.

Other words are lofty (rising to a great height, very tall and impressive), altitudinous (extending to a great distance upward), statuesque (tall and beautiful, of a woman), rangy (tall and thin, of a person), etc. All these words can be looked up on [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) or [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) for more elaborate descriptions and example sentences (except altitudinous, which is not found on the Oxford Dictionary site).

Comment: Also, _lanky_..

Answer (score 1):

altitudinous: extending to a great distance upward
immeasurable: very great in size or amount : impossible to measure
Alpine: (capitalized) a person possessing Alpine physical characteristics
monumental: of or relating to a monument

Reference: Merriam-Webster dictionary

Comment: Guys, can we get some definitions and references to external authorities (i.e. dictionaries) here, please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the word *gargantuan*.